# javascript doesn't load until page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, browser

hello good people of the interwebs. i have some ad code that works just fine on one of my pages, but when i use it on another, it doesn't load unless i refresh my browser. i'm not a programmer but i have searched high and low and tried multiple tips to get it to work. i tried (window).load, i tried (document).ready but nothing did the trick. here's what i have and i'm hoping someone can point out something new i should try:

```
<script type\="text/javascript">
vm_load({
"displayId": "12584",
"publisherId": "33927",
"campaign": "9380",
"maxResults": "3",
"areaofstudy":
JSON.parse(jQuery.cookie('CategorySubCategorySpecialty')).CATEGORIES[0].text.replace('Business','1').replace('Criminal Justice & Legal','3').replace('Education','5').replace('Fine Arts & Design','2').replace('Health & Medicine','8').replace('Liberal Arts & Humanities','5').replace('Math, Science & Engineering','9').replace('Public Affairs & Social Sciences','13').replace('Religious Studies','5').replace('Technology','9').replace('Vocational Training',''),
"md": "1"
});
</script>
```

UPDATE: I had erroneously copied the script declaration that included the backslash. Removing it does not help, in fact having it there would probably stop the code from loading at all, right?

jQuery is loaded on the page.

I think I need something that wraps around the code and tells it to load after the page is finished loading. Could that be the solution?

Comment: it's probably cuz you don't have the correct script tag `<script type\="text/javascript">`, remove that slash before the `=` sign

Comment: How about moving this code to the bottom of the page ... just before `</body>`? And you do not need `type\="text/javascript"` .. `<script>` works just fine.

Comment: Is jquery imported before this script?

Comment: removing the slash doesn't help.

Comment: jQuery is imported before this script, but i am thinking i need something that tell this javascript to wait until everything else is loaded before it loads. maybe that could work?

Comment: Where is this js placed in the DOM? header or body? also wrapping it in $(document).ready(function(){//Code here}); should technically do what your saying, but you said you have tried it? did you try logging inside of it? Also, is the console spitting any errors out?

Comment: this is placed in the body. it's on a CMS that i have no control over so this is the only place i can put it. it works perfectly on another implementation that is set up the same way.

i'm not sure what is meant by 'logging inside of it'. sorry, i'm not truly fluent in all of this.

Comment: and your not getting any errors from the console on the page that it's not loading on? In between the opening script tag and the vm_load function place console.log('JS is working'); and check to see if that shows up in the console, that will tell us if its a problem with the function or the js in general.

Comment: @Bradley : i added the console.log code but it actually broke most of the page (only the header and footer displayed).

Comment: a console.log() should never effect a page, which makes me think theres a bigger problem at hand, remove the log and check for errors, if you dont know how, just hit inspect element in chrome of FF and go to the console tab, it will display any errors that the JS is giving you, and could pinpoint the problem.

Comment: i'm starting to think it's the JSON code that i'm using. i have that in there to pull out a category name from a cookie that is created, and then convert that name to a numerical parameter that gets passed in the ad call. when i just removed the JSON string and replaced it with a number, in this case "14", the ad loaded immediately. only problem is i really need the cookie information in order to filter the ad correctly. ugh. hoping some of you have some ideas @YoannM

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error

```
<script type\="text/javascript">
```

Use `<script>` or `<script type="text/javascript">` instead

Comment: sorry, the backslash was a mistake. removing it does not help my problem.